# Windows 7 MySQL Error 1067 Services Will not Start

Tags: mysql, service, innodb, mysql-error-1067

This has been a nightmare of a problem.  I initially installed WAMP and everything worked fine.  I restarted my computer and MySQL server hasn't worked since.  I have been trying to install just MySQL and the "SQL Instance Config" freezes and when trying to start the service I receive the "Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly". I have searched for hours online trying all of the various solutions. These are the main ones that I recall seeing the most.

1. Changing the install paths to ones without spaces
2. Deleting all mySQL files and reinstalling
3. Starting the services through the command Prompt

Here is a copy of the errors file.  I believe somewhere with this InnoDB lies the problem, but I can't seem to be able to solve it.

- 121203 22:20:59 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
- 121203 22:20:59 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
- 121203 22:20:59 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
- 121203 22:20:59 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
- 121203 22:20:59  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
- 121203 22:20:59 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
- 121203 22:20:59 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
- 121203 22:20:59 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: INNODB
- 121203 22:20:59 [ERROR] Aborting
- 121203 22:20:59 [Note] C:\mysql\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete

This seems like such a common problem, that I would think there would be more definitive solutions, but I'm hoping that someone will be able to help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Well one thing that springs to mind is that the installation is not running with local administrator privileges: the  bit about -- 121203 22:20:59 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this for my Windows Server 2012 installation to opening up the properties dialog for the MySQL56 service, go to the login tab then click the local system account radio button, then the MySQL56 service started up ok.